# Error when transferring a file via Bluetooth to a Samsung Galaxy phone

Tags: bluetooth, smartphone, transfer

I am using Ubuntu Natty. I want to transfer files to and from my samsung galaxy which is running froyo. But every time I try to transfer a file from my Samsung Galaxy phone to Ubuntu natty I get the message

```
Remote device rejected your request
```

on my phone. I don't know what to do about it. Can someone please help me or point me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you pair those devices? Press the Super key, type *Bluetooth*, and follow directions (can't go into details as I have no BT adapter right now).

Comment: Yes. I paired  them.  But I get that  errors  regardless. In any case I will try wat you have suggested. Thanks

Comment: @htorque Could you please tell me, what do you mean by the super key? Should I press it alone or in combination with some other key?

Comment: You can also try my answer to similar question, here is a [link](http://askubuntu.com/a/397672/59876).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Had the same problem with SGS2, solved by going (on pc) into Bluetooth Preferences -> Receive Files and switching "Receive files into Download folder over bluetooth" back and forth

Answer (score 1):

Well I did have this problem and I just figured this out. Make sure your computer has "Allow Bluetooth Devices To Find This Computer" selected. Then follow this:

Start -> search -> Bluetooth File Transfer

Click this then click "Receive Files". Now you are ready to receive files from any other devices!

I think it works brilliantly but I am using Windows 7. It might be different for Windows XP. But I am sorry, I don't know. Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Bluetooth applet > **Properties** > **Enable receive files**, then try it again.

Answer (score 0):

`s6102 setting > Application > Running Services > Bluetooth share > Stop`

Finish, then go for new transfer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error you have received, I would suggest you to install something like "blueman" since it have better options and I bet this will solve your issue because I too have the same issue with my sony ericsson.

Installation is pretty simple, just search blueman in synaptic/software center.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the Bluetooth applet > Properties > join a personal area network