# How to Send Files to My Computer via Bluetooth?

Tags: bluetooth

I can pair my HTC One X with Ubuntu, but I can't send any files to my computer from my phone. Every time I try my phone reports the transfer failed and I never get prompted by the computer to accept the file.

Comment: you can use an FTP server on your phone like swiftp

Comment: flag received: possible duplicate? http://askubuntu.com/questions/153652/no-receive-option-in-bluetooth-settings

Comment: Are you using Blueman on the Ubuntu desktop?

Answer (score 5):

Search for "Personal file sharing".  Then activate "Receive files over Bluetooth".  That is it, worked for me.

Comment: Unfortunately this stopped working after Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to share one method on how to send files from any Android smartphone to Ubuntu. I successfully tested it myself on Ubuntu 12.10 laptop with built-in bluetooth adapter and SGS4 smartphone.

Your smartphone and Ubuntu computer should be paired.

Open a terminal application (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) and install `obexftp` and `obexpushd` packages from [OpenOBEX project](http://openobex.sourceforge.net/downloads.html) using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install obexftp obexpushd
```

Set your computer's bluetooth adapter into discoverable mode executing the following command:

```
sudo hciconfig hci0 piscan
```

Run `obexpushd` command and listen to the incoming bluetooth connection:

```
obexpushd -B
```

Now it is possible to send any file from the smartphone to Ubuntu computer. The files will be stored in your `/home/username` or `/home/username/Downloads` directory.

I tested the method by sharing a file through bluetooth from ASTRO File Manager on Android smartphone.

The main credit for this method goes to the [blog post](http://blog.mypapit.net/2007/10/howto-send-and-recieve-files-over-bluetooth-with-ubuntu-linux.html).

Answer (score 0):

Open up the file browser, then find the icon for your phone on the side, click on it and find the file using the computer.

Then just drag to where you want it.

May not work for you but worth a try.

Comment: I'm affected by the bug that doesn't allow me to browse my files, so that won't work. However, I have found a temporary fix: I went to Personal File Sharing and set it up to download Bluetooth files automatically from my set up devices.

Answer (score 0):

I installed blueman for any bluetooth connection, because on every pc with ubuntu i tried to use it, it didn't work. 
Give it a try

```
sudo apt-get install blueman
```

And then start it. It should now be on the startup applications list. 
It's lot more comfortable and customizable than the stock obex.